# How, from input-string, generate number (/sum) from assigned values from each letter in the input-string (e.g: name = input('enter letters: ' )

Tags: python

From input-string, generate number (/sum) from assigned values from each letter in the input-string (e.g: name = input('enter letters: ' )

Let's say that A=1, B=2, C=3.......(etc)
How can I get printed a number as output from these input letters in the input-string:
*letters = input ('enter letters: ')*-------->e.g writing ABC when prompted, then return the sum of (A+B+C)------>print (name)------>6

Thanks,
Alsing

Comment: Hello Alsing Selnes! welcome to Stack Overflow. The point of the sight is to create a library of knowledge, without any "debug/write my code" questions. In light of that, could you please tell us specifically what your problem is, and what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ord` to get the ASCII value and modulo:

```
letters = input("Enter letters: ")
res = sum(map(lambda x: ord(x.upper())%65+1, letters))
print(res)
```

Here I used map, because I like it but you can also use list-comprehension:

```
letters = input("Enter letters: ")
res = sum([ord(letter.upper())%65 + 1 for letter in letters])
print(res)
```

Gives the same results:

```
Enter letters: ABC
6
```

EDIT: For Python2 you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`

```
letters = raw_input("Enter letters: ")
res = sum(map(lambda x: ord(x.upper())%65+1, letters))
print(res)
```

If you want different numbers you can create a function instead of using `lambda` function and play a little with math.

For example, if you want all the value to range from 1 to 9:

```
def get_letter_value(letter):
    value = ord(letter.upper()) % 65  # Gives the standard value starting by 0
    return (value % 9) + 1  # Limits from 1-9 resetting each time

letters = raw_input("Enter letters: ")
res = sum(map(get_letter_value, letters))
print res
```

Usage:

```
Enter letters: BMZ
14
```

It's just playing with math, specially with the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: Hi palvarez, Do I have to import something beforehand? Because I get this error message; "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alsing\Desktop\Python\proposed.py", line 5, in <module>
    letters = input("Enter letters: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ABC' is not defined"

Comment: @AlsingSelnes Nothing to import, it seems you are adding a new line trying to use ABC as variable without setting it. Just having the three lines of code I gave you it's enough

Comment: I just copy and paste your 3 lines into VS Code, but the error message pops up anyway.

Comment: Ah! you are using Python2 I updated my answer for you :)

Comment: That worked, thanks. If I want to make the letters in a non-increasing way as in the example, butin, let's say a-->i belongs to the  numbers 1-->9, and j-->r belongs to the numbers 1-->9, and lastly s-->z belongs to 1-->8. Will the same code work for if I type in BMZ (which should be the number 14)? Or even make the numbers random?

Comment: Not eactly the same code. Instead of doing `lambda` function you could have a defined function that receives the letter and according its`ord` value the output changes, and have conditions like `if 0 < ord(x)%65 < 8 return 1`

Comment: I've been struggling all day with what you suggested, but can't seem to get it right, so I would appreciate some help. :-) (PS: just getting started with Python btw.)

Comment: @AlsingSelnes Ah! You should have said  that sooner I will give you more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use keys in a dictionary to assign the values of a letter.

```
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
numbers = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(letters, start=1)}
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e', 6: 'f', 7: 'g', 8: 'h', 9: 'i', 10: 'j', 11: 'k', 12: 'l', 13: 'm', 14: 'n', 15: 'o', 16: 'p', 17: 'q', 18: 'r', 19: 's', 20: 't', 21: 'u', 22: 'v', 23: 'w', 24: 'x', 25: 'y', 26: 'z'}
```

You would then write your function to use dictionary with your `input` method.
Enumerating can also be used conditionally which you can implement:

```
numbers = range(10)

new_d = {n: n**2 for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0}
print(new_d)
```

Output:

```
{0: 0, 2: 4, 4: 16, 6: 36, 8: 64}
```